# facebook share link not show fetured image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

when i share my site post in facebook then not show that post featured image in facebook. show different default image. how i can solve this? my [site link](http://bangladeshtime.com/)
i already use this open graph code.. but it's not work

```html
   <meta property="og:title" content="Bangladesh Time">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://bangladeshtime.com/">
     <meta property="og:image" content="http://bangladeshtime.com/_files/mainlogo.png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Bangladesh Time">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is to small. The minimum image size is 200*200px regarding to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices?locale=de_DE#images).

**Edit:** In your website's markup i can't find the open graph tags. In addition, your markup is invalid:

```html
<center><img src='http://bangladeshtime.com/head-test-eng.jpg'></center>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
  ...
```